# Levantar aplicación en localhost - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un problema. Quiero iniciar una nueva instancia de mi App desde Visual Studio (C#).

La misma levanta en `http://localhost:54619/`. El problema, es que al iniciar, se crea un bucle en el método `Application_BeginRequest()` de la clase `Global.asax.cs` y no sale nunca de ahí. Intenté redirigirlo con `Response.RedirectToRoute("Default")`, pero no funciona, no puedo salir de ese método.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Principal");
}
```

Estoy utilizando ASP.NET MVC, IIS Express.

Comment: Y cual es el codigo que provoca el bucle?

Comment: En realidad cualquiera, es independiente de lo que escriba dentro del método. Yo supongo que el problema es que al llamar a localhost, la aplicación siempre entra por `Application_BeginRequest()` y como que no puede salir de ahi.

Comment: que pasa si simplemente quitas el Application_BeginRequest ? no deberias redirecionar en cada request

Comment: Recuerda que Application_BeginRequest() es para *todos* los requests! es decir incluso en el principal. ¿Cual es el efecto que quieres lograr?Ir siempre al Principal cuando va al raiz el sitio? Esto se logra con Rutas en ASP.NET MVC, precisamente con la ruta por default

Answer (score 1):

Estás haciendo un bucle infinito.

Cuando comienza cualquier request lo redireccionas a `~/Principal`. luego al hacer el request a `~/Principal` se vuelve a redireccionar antes de que este se ejecute ¿adivina a donde?. Sí a `~/Principal` y así sucesivamente siempre redirecciona una y otra vez hacía "~/Principal" y por lo tanto la redirección nunca se acaba.

¿Que es lo que tratas de hacer realmente?

Comment: Bien, antes que nada gracias. El controlador "Principal" esta configurado para levantar la aplicacion (desde su metodo Index()), el problema justamente es que no estoy logrando ejecutarlo de manera correcta.

Comment: @ZottoSL No entiendi tu explicación.

Answer (score 1):

Como te comentan, la redirección de un `BeginRequest` del Global.asax se ejecutará **siempre**.

Podrías lograr que si no coloca nada en la dirección, o sea va la raíz del sitio de la aplicación direccione al controlador principal. Esto se hace con una routa por default.

Por ejemplo, mira en el controlador que va por default si no se envía un controlador:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Principal", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
}
```

Pero dependiendo de la funcionalidad requerida, hay varias formas de "atacar el problema", como puede ser *route constraints* personalizado utilizando [IRouteConstraint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs), Filters, etc.

Más información:

- [ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)
- [Creating a Route Constraint (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs)
- [IRouteConstraint: Creating a Custom Route Constraint C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs)